# Using TimestampedGeoJson to plot point groupings from received input

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium

I'm trying to simulate receiving data from an external output and plotting that data onto a map as it is received. I have around 1700 latitude, longitude and timestamp points that I want to plot but in a controlled manner - meaning I would like to simulate that I'm receiving for example 3 points at a time, plotting those points on a map, then receiving three more, plotting those, and so on.

So far, using the TimestampedGeoJson function from the folium library, I've succeeded in creating a map on which all of my points appear at the right place and time in sequence based on a defined time increment. But, as mentioned, this is using a geojson folder that already has all of the values inside it - I would like to start off with none, receive some values, plot them, receive more, plot those, etc. This is my code so far for converting json inputs to geojson and then plotting that:

```
my_map = folium.Map(starting_coords, zoom_start = 13)
TimestampedGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [d["lon"], d["lat"]],
            },
            "properties": {
                "style": {"color" : ''},
                "icon": "circle",
                "iconstyle":{
                    "fillOpacity": 0.8,
                    "stroke": "true",
                    "radius": 5
                },
                "times": [d["times"]]
            }
        } for d in data
    ]
},
loop = False, period = 'PT10S').add_to(my_map)

my_map.save("test.html")
webbrowser.open("test.html")
```

I can receive the inputs in csv or json format without issue - the problem is finding a way to tell the TimestampedGeoJson function to plot 3 values, stop, wait for more, plot the next 3, etc. I think I can create a loop which gradually fills a geojson with received inputs without too much difficulty but how do I make sure that each 3 point grouping is plotted on the same map and not a new map every time?